# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, site-statistics

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Science Fiction & Fantasy breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                 11         17
Users destroyed                                 160          0
Users deleted                                    19          0
Users contacted                                  26          0
User banned from review                           3          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            57      4,584
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               65      2,706
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        229      9,725
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               96      3,508
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               137      7,666
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               88      6,992
Tags merged                                      60          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             9          4
Tag synonyms created                             11          2
Revisions redacted                                2          0
Questions unprotected                             2         10
Questions reopened                               93        217
Questions protected                              24        313
Questions migrated                               25          4
Questions merged                                  4          0
Questions flagged⁴                                4      1,164
Questions closed                                128      1,838
Question flags handled⁴                         389        779
Posts unlocked                                   10         26
Posts undeleted                                  63        133
Posts locked                                     12        241
Posts deleted⁵                                  958      3,589
Posts bumped                                      0        664
Escalations to the CM team                        4          0
Comments undeleted                              107          0
Comments flagged                                 15      3,651
Comments deleted⁶                             6,108      4,825
Comment flags handled                         2,981        685
Answers flagged                                  49      8,609
Answer flags handled                          2,595      6,063
All comments on a post moved to chat             51          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Should I even dare ask what "Users destroyed" means?

Comment: @Loki see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user