# 2019: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, site-statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
>   -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges 
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together. 
And what could be more festive than a big pile of numbers? 
So here is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Science Fiction & Fantasy over the past 12 months:

```
                  Action                  Moderators Community¹
----------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  21         28
Users destroyed³                                 199          0
Users deleted                                     78          0
Users contacted                                   30          0
User banned from review                            2          0
Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue             83      4,918
Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue                54      2,604
Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue         155      8,434
Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue                35      3,025
Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue                165      6,847
Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue                79      6,622
Tags merged                                       29          0
Tag synonyms proposed                              2          0
Tag synonyms created                               2          0
Revisions redacted                                 3          0
Questions unprotected                              1          4
Questions reopened                                97        208
Questions protected                               14        248
Questions migrated                                17          3
Questions merged                                   8          0
Questions flagged⁵                                12      1,375
Questions closed                                 133      1,740
Question flags handled⁵                          508        875
Posts unlocked                                     1          4
Posts undeleted                                   50         88
Posts locked                                      10        188
Posts deleted⁶                                   580      3,560
Posts bumped                                       0        347
Escalations to the Community Manager team          8          0
Comments undeleted                               128          0
Comments flagged                                  16      3,803
Comments deleted⁷                              6,060      5,333
Comment flags handled                          2,922        891
Bounties canceled                                  1          0
Answers flagged                                   45      7,655
Answer flags handled                           1,809      5,891
All comments on a post moved to chat              49          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? I posted a similar report here last year: [2018: a year in moderation](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12259/2018-a-year-in-moderation)...
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222019%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341507/2019-a-year-in-closing)

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Are there statistics for questions manually removed from Hot Network Questions? Or has that not actually ever happened?

Comment: @Alex [never happened](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1173607/find-posts-by-history-event-type?HistoryEventType=53). If anyone's curious, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327323/398063) are the IDs of the various types of history events (body edited, question unprotected, etc), sorted by who can trigger them (anyone, mod powers, etc). For instance, running the same query for [politics.se] yields [12 results](https://data.stackexchange.com/politics/query/1173607/find-posts-by-history-event-type?HistoryEventType=53).

Comment: I'm really pleased with what seems like a healthy self-moderating community. Thank you everyone.

Comment: Is there any way to break out the count of  comment flags for "no longer needed" from the other types?

Comment: This is hella dope. It's nice seeing how all the contributions my community and I made all add up. We're more lit than I thought.